# How many solutions does the equation have? (Inclusion-exclusion principle)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion, integer-partitions

How many solutions does the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1$ have? $x_i$ are integers between $-3$ and $3$.

Hints please!

Comment: Hint: perform a change of variables $y_i=x_i+3$.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem with that !

Comment: How many solutions does the equation x1+x2+x3+x4=1
have? xi are integers between −3 and 3

.

"Hints please!"  Try listing them all and see if you find a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will be easier to understand if you first read [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/).

First, you *biject* the problem to:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 13$, where each $x_i \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$

Then, you use inclusion exclusion.

$T_k$ will represent the following computation:

- each of the $\binom{4}{k}$ possible combinations of $k$ of the variables will be examined.
- for each such combination, it will be assumed that the minimum value of the pertinent variables is $7$ rather than 0.  That is, the $k$ variables will all be presumed to be out of bounds.
- the $4 - k$ remaining variables will be left unconstrained (i.e. minimum value = 0, they may or may not be out of bounds).
- the number of solutions possible for each such combination will be computed by bijecting the existing equation to one that adjusts for the pertinent variables being **forced** to be out of bounds.
- $T_k$ will represent the sum of the number of solutions possible for each of the $\binom{4}{k}$ combinations.

Consistent with [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) the answer will be 
$T_0 - T_1 + T_2 - T_3 + \cdots - \cdots$

$T_0 = \binom{16}{3}.$

By symmetry 
$T_1 = 4 \times$ the number of solutions where $x_1 \geq 7.$ 
Using the analysis in the cited article, 
$T_1 = 4 \times \binom{9}{3}.$

At this point, the analysis stops, because it is impossible to have 2 or more constraints out of bounds and still have the sum be $\leq 13.$

Final answer:

$$\binom{16}{3} - [4 \times \binom{9}{3}].$$

Comment: More accurately, $T_k$ is an *overcount* of the number of solutions that violate at least $k$ upper bounds. Otherwise, $T_0-T_1$ would be the correct formula.

Comment: @RobPratt You're right.  I subconsciously balked at precision of expression because I couldn't combine precision with elegance of expression.  Describing $T_k$ as an *overcount* is accurate but simply too ambiguous.  See my revision, which opts for precision.